# How to return Complex types from a WCF Data Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to return a complex type from a WCF data service that is made of collections of entity types ?

for example :

```
 //the complex type to return
 class Entities
 {
    ICollection<Contract> Contracts;
    ...

 }

 //configuration
 public partial class MyContext: DbContext
 {
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=DBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Entities>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasKey(c=>c.Id);
        ...
    }
    ...
  }

 //the WCF Data Service
 public class PricingDataService : DataService<ObjectContext>, IDisposable
 {
     [WebGet]
     public Entities GetEntities()
     {
         return new Entities();
     }
  }
```

When I try the above configuration, I get an exception :

```
" The exception message is 'One or more validation errors 
were detected during model     generation: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: 
Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'Contract' was already 
defined."
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: I get an exception : "The exception message is 'One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'Contract' was already defined."

Comment: So, this would seem to have nothing to do with returning the complex type. It is a problem with your model.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a problem with my model because when I comment this line of code : modelBuilder.ComplexType<Entities>(); the error disappears .

Comment: And, what is it that `modelBuilder` builds? And are we both looking at the same error message? "One or more validation errors 
were detected during **model** generation"

Comment: modelBuilder is called within the OnModelCreating method to specify primary keys and certain behaviors of my model entities.

Comment: Does it build the model at all?

Comment: It builds if I comment out the line mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible because if you define this, it means that complex type has navigation property to contracts. This is not allowed in whole entity framework. The error probably comes from some infering where `Contract` is already defined as entity but complext type is trying to map it as something else - but this is just guess.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this behavior ?

Comment: Not sure how this works with Data services. You can use custom not mapped type but the question is how Data service handle this?

Comment: Why don't you just query for set of contracts from client?

Comment: I have maybe 12 entities that should be queried regularly and that are tightly related to each other. I need to send back this graph of objects so that the client does not inadvertantly forget to query one or two entities that might have changed in the meantime. do you have a recommmendation for that ?

Comment: That looks like a case for a custom wcf service. Not for wcf data service.

Comment: I'm using wcf service because what I'm doing mostly is just exposing data to clients, I'm not doing any processing.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the snippet you posted is hard to read for me.  However, I can tell you that I have sent via WCF types like those.  I usually don't use ICollection<> to declare my lists, I tend to use List<> instead and have never had much of a problem receiving the information on the client.

Maybe it's a problem on how you're defining the class on your data contract.

Comment: I am curious as to how you do that. in your complex types, do you have Lists of entity types ?

Comment: Correct. I have something like this as my data contract: public class SomeClass { private List<SomeEntity> mCustomers; public List<SomeEntity> Customers{get{return mCustomers;}set{mCustomers = value}} } Then in my service: public SomeClass GetSome(){...} I don't know yet how to post snippets. I'll try to whip up something later.

Comment: please do post it. that'd go a long way in helping me figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: are you using "WCF Data Services" ? the one based on REST ? we're not talking abt SOAP services.